# How to get image attachments from multiple (specified) posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm looking for a method to pull thumbnails as well as the source for the large image (to be used as a mini gallery) that pulls image attachments from **multiple specified** post ID's.

Basically a query for post attachments that combines all the images into one mini gallery.

I've seen how to pull image attachments from a single post, but no idea how to pull image attachments from multiple posts?

In other words, can we pull image attachments from a specified array of posts?

Below is the code i'm using to pull ALL attachments throughout the site:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => null ); 
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        the_title();
        the_attachment_link($post->ID, false);
        the_excerpt();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you bold out **specified** but then say **but no idea how to pull image attachments from multiple posts?** whats the question? The actual image functions for that are [Here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4/wp-includes/media.php#L613) & [Here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4/wp-includes/media.php#L649)

Comment: to pull image attachments from more than one post at a time... say I have 3 posts- and I want to pull all image attachments from only those 3.

Comment: Or better yet--- specify a Post ID of a parent page and pull all attachments from it's child pages..

Comment: Did you find an answer for this @Joe ?

Answer (score 0):

After much searching I had to conclude there is no elegant way to do this with just one WP_query. Instead you can call a new query for each post_id and combine the resulting attachment ids into one array. Use this array for your further purposes.